# Change text string in a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, filters

I'm using the WooCommerce Waitlist plugin, but I'd like to change it to be for products that haven't been released yet, ie for "expressions of interest".

To do this I need to change a lot of strings, for example one that says "Join the waitlist to be emailed when this product becomes available".

I've found where this is set in the plugin: the file...

> wcwl-waitlist-template-functions.php

... in the root folder of the plugin.

If this was a theme I could replicate this file in my child theme and modify the strings, but as it's a plugin I'm all out at sea. And redeclaring the function causes an error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the code of the function...

```
/**
 * Get the default intro text to display above the waitlist dependent on product type
 *
 * @param string $product_type simple/variation/grouped (variation is the same as simple by default)
 * @param bool   $user_is_on_waitlist
 *
 * @return mixed|void
 */
function wcwl_get_intro_text( $product_type = 'simple', $user_is_on_waitlist = false ) {
    $context = 'join';
    $text    = __( 'Join the waitlist to be emailed when this product becomes available', 'woocommerce-waitlist' );
    if ( $user_is_on_waitlist ) {
        $context = 'leave';
        $text    = __( 'You are on the waitlist for this product', 'woocommerce-waitlist' );
    } elseif ( 'grouped' === $product_type || 'event' === $product_type ) {
        $context = $product_type;
        $text    = __( 'Check the box alongside any Out of Stock products and update the waitlist to be emailed when those products become available', 'woocommerce-waitlist' );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wcwl_' . $context . '_waitlist_message_text', $text );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to change texts using a **translation** file.

By default, plugin texts are in the English language. Even your site language is English, You are able to generate a new language file and change texts on it.

Imagine that the plugin folder name (plugin slug, plugin text domain) is **my-plugin** and Your site language is set to **English (UK)** in *Admin Dashboard -> Settings -> General Settings -> Site Language*.

So, Create a new translation using [Poedit](https://poedit.net/download) and set the translation language to **English (UK)**. Then change texts as You want and save the translation file. You can use the `pot` file that comes with the plugin and most of the time it exists in the `language` folder.

It will give You two files named as `en_GB.po` and `en_GB.mo`. Rename files to `my-plugin-en_GB.po` and `my-plugin-en_GB.mo` and move them to `wp-content/languages/plugins` folder. Refresh the site and texts should be changed.

Comment: Thanks @Hector, I've managed to use this approach for most strings, however for some (such as the above) the translation didn't work, so for these I needed to apply Chetan Vaghela's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can change text using filter. add below code in active theme's functions.php file to change text form join waitlist message.
Here is a documentation where you can take reference. : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-waitlist/

```
add_filter( 'wcwl_join_waitlist_message_text', 'change_string_from_woo_wait_list',10,1 );
function change_string_from_woo_wait_list($text)
{
    $text = __( 'Custom Text' ); // change text here
    return $text;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks @Chetan_Vaghela, this is a good approach for targeting a small number of strings (I don't know why someone downvoted your answer). Because I had a lot of strings to change I mainly used Hector's approach, but because some translations didn't work, I had to use your approach as well. It's a shame I can't mark both answers as correct!

Comment: It's okay. somebody down-voted my answer. i have followed approach given by plugin documentation. i thought it is proper way to do change string using filter action which is provided by plugin.